# Can I interpret Standardized Regression Coefficients for an Interaction Term?

Tags: interaction, interpretation, regression-coefficients, standardization

can I interpret standardized regression coefficients for an interaction term that is based on a binary and continuous variable? How would I interpret it: Would I add the standardized coefficients if the binary variable equals 1 analogous to interpreting the "normal" regression coefficients?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you doing this in `R`?